# how to save output file in C drive for C++

Tags: c++

Ive been able to succesfully create a file, rename it, and then save it, however I need help in trying to save it in the C:\ drive but no luck.

```
string filename, newfile;

ifstream wordInFile(filename); 

cout << "Please enter filename to open" << endl;
cin >> filename;


cout << "Please enter the name for your new file" << endl;
cin >> newfile;

ofstream tempFile(newfile);       //Creating and opening a temporary file to store the needed words




wordInFile.close(); //Close the input file

tempFile.close();    //Close the temp output file
```

Comment: Make sure you have permission to write to the root of C.

Comment: How would i check for that? I would assume im already root since its in my Desktop

Comment: ***How would i check for that?*** Use your OS file explorer. Create files. If you get prompted for UAC elevation you will have to modify your program to handle that.

Comment: ***I would assume im already root since its in my Desktop*** Your Desktop should not be at the root of your OS drive. For example my Desktop folder on the current Windows 10 machine is at `C:\Users\dresc\Desktop`

Comment: You are opening the `ifstream` with a blank `filename` before you have prompted the user for the value of `filename`.  Move the opening of the `ifstream` after the prompt.

Comment: Be aware that Windows filesystem is UTF-16, so if your directory contains special UTF-8 characters (_e.g._ Japanese kanji, Russian Cyrillic, ...), this program is likely to fail.  You should prefer `std::wstring` when referring to file names in Windows.

Comment: A further note, if the user enters a filename containing spaces, your program will completely fall over.  Consider using `std::getline` to read the full input instead of just the first whitespace-separated string.

Comment: Apologies. I thought you were trying to write the file to C:\, not to the desktop folder. C:\ is often locked down for very understandable security reasons

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the order:

```
string filename, newfile;
cout << "Please enter filename to open" << endl;
cin >> filename;

ifstream wordInFile(filename);
```

In general, you want to have valid content in your variables before you use them.